# Contact Validation in android

Tags: android

In this I am trying to validate phone number . but even if i do enter correct number it wont verify. code is below

```
    cont=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editcontact);


    final String MobilePattern = "[0-9]{10}";
    btn_log=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_log);
    btn_log.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           final String phn=cont.getText().toString();


           if (!phn.matches(MobilePattern)) {
               Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid Contact number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           } else {

               Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
               startActivity(i);

           }
       }

   });
```

Comment: It's not clear if your EditText is setup to only accept phone numbers using `inputType="phone"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your regex is proper but you are using it in incorrect way, you need to compile your pattern before using it to match.

```
String  patterntomatch ="[0-9]{10}";
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(patterntomatch);
Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(phn);

if (!matcher.find()) {
    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid Contact number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
   //To get matching text you can use
   String ans = phn.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
   Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
           startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: your input should be 10 characters only. if you pass extra it will not work, and you are passing alphabet so your regex will fail. what is your exact requirement.

Comment: after edit know is correct answer one up-vote for it

Answer (score 0):

first try

```
 final String phn=cont.getText().toString().trim();
```

it will help you when your content contains any spaces.

---

try by changing below things

```
 final String MobilePattern = "[0-9]";
 .......
 final String phn=cont.getText().toString().trim();
 .........

 if (!phn.matches(MobilePattern) || phn.length() != 10 ) {
           Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid Contact number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
```

Comment: `"[0-9]{10}"` from the question wouldn't be wrong. Here, you're only matching one digit

Comment: try with  final String phn=cont.getText().toString().trim(); @AseelAli

Comment: @cricket_007 yeah that's true.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am giving you two step simple solution, At the very first allow user only take the valid input.

> So use in your `XML.`

```
android:digits="0123456789"
android:inputType="phone"
android:maxLength="10"
```

Hopefully you can easily can understand each line meaning. Secondly you can validate on button click like below is given.

```
tv_login.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (!isValidMobile(etPhone.getText().toString())){
            //Invalid Mobile Number
        }else {
            //Valid Mobile Number
        }
    });

private boolean isValidMobile(String phone) {
    boolean check = false;
    if (!Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", phone)) {
        if (phone.length() < 10 || phone.length() > 10) {
            check = false;
        } else {
            check = true;
        }
    } else {
        check = false;
    }
    return check;
}
```